# Do I need a wrapper class for p/invoke'ing a few functions from user32.dll

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, wrapper

So I am working on a c# Windows Form application and part of my code uses some methods from user32.dll. Listed them below.

- public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
- public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
- public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
- public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
- public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId
- public static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii)

At first I had them in the file with all the main forms code as part of the `public partial class MainForm` and this all works. Then when I ran code analysis in Visual Studio Community 2015 it complained that "because they are P/Invoke methods they should be defined in a class named NativeMethods, SafeNativeMethods, or UnsafeNativeMethods.

So being the good coder I am who always obeys the whims of his IDE I promptly make a new class file and run into the first issue.

> Would the class containing these functions be unsafe (is it also unmanaged)? Which name
>   should I use and should the class be declared as `internal static` with the `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` attribute?

As I did more reading to try to figure this out I kept coming across references to making a wrapper class for the code so I started looking into that. That yielded tons of stuff about security and wrappers for c++ or c, prototypes, and tons of other information that doesn't seem helpful and got myself completely lost.

> So I guess what I want to know is two things. 1st, would I need to (or
>   would it be best practice to do so) make a wrapper class to use these
>   methods, and if so, how would I go about doing it?
>
> 2nd, If I make the class Unsafe/SafeNativeMethods should I call it
>   safe or unsafe? Should all the methods be left public? Or do should
>   have the methods declared private and write some getters/setters like:

```
public IntPtr getGetForegroundWindow()
{
    return GetForegroundWindow()
}
```

or

```
public setSendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr, lParam)
{
    SendMessage(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Or do I need to use delegates or something instead of setters and getters?

Sorry about the question being a bit of a brain dump. Every time I think I found an answer I just end up with more questions and all the talk of safe/unsafe/security has me worried. I don't mind google searches and reading up on topics but the reading list just to figure out what to read is getting huge so figured I would stop and ask here to see if I am even asking the right question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a static class.

```
namespace NativeMethods
{
    public static class User32
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, ref RECT lParam);
    }
}
```

Only create a wrapper when it does something, like holding a state of parameter conversion/checking.

---

**Cases when you want to wrap pInvokes**

An example for wrapping PInvoke methods could be when the native method allocates memory and returns a handle. This case you'll need to create a wrapper that keeps track of a handle. It should implement the `IDisposable` for releasing the unmanaged resources.

for *(pseudo)* example: *(you should check the dispose pattern)*

```
public class MyWrapper : IDisposable
{
    [DllImport("MyLibrary.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr DoAllocSomeMemory(int size);

    [DllImport("MyLibrary.dll")]
    private static extern void ReleaseMe(IntPtr handle);


    private IntPtr _handle;

    public MyWrapper()
    {
        _handle = DoAllocSomeMemory(8000);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ReleaseMe(_handle);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Should it be in the same namespace as the MainForm?

Comment: Normally you want to reuse these classes in multiple projects, so I would place them in a separate library.

Comment: In my case they will never be reused but I want to make sure I am following best practices. Just to clarify, you are suggesting I make a second project that is a class library and then reference this new class library in the original project?

Comment: Yes, this way you can reuse that library for other projects.